# Is there a way to get a permanent download url for images in AWS Amplify Storage? (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, flutter-aws-amplify

I need to regenerate a url to download images from AWS Amplify S3 when the token expires. Is there no permanent way to get a link for a specific image? Thank you!